Why doesn't my highly animated reverse work
Opacity is effective both on and off, height changes only have animation effects when turned on, and not when turned off.
The following is a runnable code that I have tried for a long time, but it has not been successful. I suspect it may be a problem with the controller. I can use the global controller to control it and execute the reverse method

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: MyHomePage(),
    ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _showDismissibleDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    Navigator.of(context).push(DismissibleDialog());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dismissible Dialog Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _showDismissibleDialog(context),
          child: Text('Show Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DismissibleDialog<T> extends PopupRoute<T> {
  @override
  Color? get barrierColor => Colors.transparent;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => 'Dismissible Dialog';

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Widget buildModalBarrier() {
    return const AnimatiedContainer(
      child: BuildBarrier(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return const AnimatiedContainer(
      child: BuildPage(),
    );
  }
}

class BuildBarrier extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildBarrier({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final opacityController =
        AnimationControllerProvider.of(context).opacityController;
    final heightController =
        AnimationControllerProvider.of(context).heightController;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: kToolbarHeight,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Future.wait([
                  opacityController.reverse(),
                  heightController.reverse(),
                ]).then((res) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                });
              },
              child: FadeTransition(
                opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 0.5).animate(
                  CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: opacityController, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BuildPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final heightController =
        AnimationControllerProvider.of(context).heightController;

    return SafeArea(
      child: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: kToolbarHeight,
              left: 0,
              child: SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(
                  CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: heightController, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
                ),
                axisAlignment: -1,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Dismissible Dialog',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatiedContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const AnimatiedContainer({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  State<AnimatiedContainer> createState() => _AnimatiedContainerState();
}

class _AnimatiedContainerState extends State<AnimatiedContainer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _opacityController;
  late final AnimationController _heightController;

  bool isExpand = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _heightController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    )..forward();

    _opacityController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    )..forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _opacityController.dispose();
    _heightController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimationControllerProvider(
      opacityController: _opacityController,
      heightController: _heightController,
      isExpand: isExpand,
      child: Container(
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimationControllerProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final AnimationController opacityController;
  final AnimationController heightController;
  final bool isExpand;

  const AnimationControllerProvider({
    Key? key,
    required this.opacityController,
    required this.heightController,
    required Widget child,
    this.isExpand = false,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  static AnimationControllerProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    final AnimationControllerProvider? result = context
        .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AnimationControllerProvider>();
    assert(result != null, 'No AnimationController found in context');
    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(AnimationControllerProvider old) {
    return opacityController != old.opacityController ||
        heightController != old.heightController;
  }
}


